# можно ли здесь оптимизировать код, поиск Laravel? оцените качество

Tags: php, laravel

```
        public function search(Request $request) 
            {
                
                $prefixLinks = [
                    'Page' => '',
                    'Painter' => 'avtomalyar/',
                    'Post' => 'post/',
                ];
                
                $query = $request->input('query');
                
                $links = [];
                
                $pages = Page::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->get();
                $painters = Painter::where('company', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('about', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->get();
                $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->get();
                
                foreach ($pages as $page){
                    $linksRow['slug'] = $prefixLinks['Page'] . $page->slug;
                    $linksRow['title'] = $page->title;
                    array_push($links, $linksRow);
                }
                
                foreach ($painters as $painter){
                    $linksRow['slug'] = $prefixLinks['Painter'] . $painter->id;
                    $linksRow['title'] = $painter->company;
                    array_push($links, $linksRow);
                }
                
                foreach ($posts as $post){
                    $linksRow['slug'] = $prefixLinks['Post'] . $post->slug;
                    $linksRow['title'] = $post->title;
                    array_push($links, $linksRow);
                }
                
    
    //отображаем VIEW
                foreach ($links as $link){
                    echo '<a href="' . url($link['slug']). '">'. $link['title'] . '</a><br>'; 
                }
            }


//Вариант 2 переделал
$request->validate([
        'query' => 'string',
    ]);
    
    $query = $request->input('query');
    
    $links = [];
    
    //Модели по каким производить поиск
    $modelsSearch = [
        
        'Page' => [
            'options' =>[
                'prefixLink' => '/',
                'getLink' => 'slug',
                'getLinkText' => 'title',
                'searchBy' => 'title',
            ],
        ],
        'Painter' => [
            'options' =>[
                
                'prefixLink' => 'avtomalyar/',
                'getLink' => 'id',
                'getLinkText' => 'company',
                'searchBy' => 'company',
            ],
        ],
        'Post' => [
            'options' =>[     
                'prefixLink' => 'post/',
                'getLink' => 'slug',
                'getLinkText' => 'title',
                'searchBy' => 'title',
            ],
        ],
    ];
    
    foreach ($modelsSearch as $modelName => $setting){
         
        $model = 'App\\Models\\'. $modelName;
        
        $searchLists = $model::where($setting['options']['searchBy'], 
                'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
        
        foreach ($searchLists as $searchList){
            $linksRow['link'] = $setting['options']['prefixLink'] . $searchList[$setting['options']['getLink']];
            $linksRow['linkText'] = $searchList[$setting['options']['getLinkText']];
            array_push($links, $linksRow);
        }
    }
    
    $collectLinks = collect($links);
    
    // convert array to collection with pagination
    $results = (new Collection($collectLinks))->paginate(self::DEFAULT_PAGINATE);
    
    return view('search', compact('results'));
```

Comment: Для этого придумали другой ресурс: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря - то что вы выложили это очень плохой код, и это очень мягко говоря. **Советы**:

---

**Валидация входных данных**. Создайте Request, провалидируйте данные, сделайте исключения и т.д.

---

**Реализуйте логику не по необходимости, а по смыслу и предназначению**. Например создайте репозиторий, реализуйте в нём метод searchPagesByQuery($query) и уже этот метод через контракт используйте в вашем методе search()

---

**Избегайте дублирования кода**. очевидно же, что у вас трижды используется один и тот же цикл foreach, меняются только данные

---

**Не используйте полнотекстовый поиск SQL**. В перспективе это в лучшем случае - рефакторинг. я бы посоветовал использовать ElasticSearch

Comment: спасибо, посмотрите переделал 2 вариант

Comment: @junior, гораздо лучше, но всё равно так не пишут. Если в реализации метода контроллера более 10 строчек - что то пошло не так)

Comment: вынести в другой метод часть то не проблема уже)

Comment: а что вы имели ввиду
Реализуйте логику не по необходимости, а по смыслу и предназначению. Например создайте репозиторий, реализуйте в нём метод searchPagesByQuery($query) и уже этот метод через контракт используйте в вашем методе search()
///////////////////Вопрос//////////
а почему не создать прям в контроллере searchPagesByQuery($query) и тут его и вызвать? self::searchPagesByQuery($query)?

Comment: Потому что этот метод вам пригодится и в других контроллерах с вероятностью 80+ процентов и всё равно придется выносить логику в репозиторий

Comment: $modelsSearch переменную можно представить как свойство класса. Например в моделях: public $prefixLink = 'chto to'; и потом очень удобно (и читаемо) использовать $model->prefixLink

Comment: В целом я представляю ваше мышление, сам через это проходил. Мне однажды помог совет "Думай классами", и это действительно правильный совет. ведь мощь php в ООП.